# How do I make Python folding in vim not visually ruin the whitespace?

Tags: python, vim, folding

When I fold Python code in vim, the fold text always starts in column zero.  This is visually noisy since Python has significant whitespace -- it looks like top-level code when I glance through the file.

Is there a setting to tell the foldtext to indent itself to the level of the first line of code being folded, short of rewriting the foldtext() method?

Answer (score 5):

The way to influence this is through the `'foldtext'` option.

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
:setlocal foldtext=repeat('\ ',indent(v:foldstart)).foldtext()
```